# Windows Phone 8 Development with Phonegap

Tags: jquery, windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have jut read this documentation `http://phonegap.com/blog/2012/12/21/apache-cordova-and-windows-phone-8/`, and I need to ask a very simple question. I know you cant do Windows Phone 8 development without Win 8 OS but if I have all my assets done on another machine say XP with like ublime Text using Jquerymobile, can I just upload my html/css/javascript to Phonegap Build and have it produce my xap files that can be submitted  to Win Phone 8 store?

Correct me if I am wrong is this not suppose to be the purpose of Phonegap Build in the first place?

Comment: Theoretically that's what Phonegap Build is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just developed an application for Android, iOS and Windows Phone 8 with jQuery Mobile and Phonegap. Theoretically you can upload your folder - as you supposed - to Phonegap Build and it is ready to run. But the store is very strict and I'm not shure if it will be certificated because of the not windows-like look and feel.

This sites helped me a lot:

http://msopentech.com/blog/2012/10/30/added-support-for-wp8-in-apache-cordova-sencha-touch-and-other-open-source-frameworks

Especially this one:

http://sgrebnov.github.io/jqmobile-wp8-theme/

It is a jquery-mobile theme provided by Microsoft itself and the application just looks native. There some special HTML-Tags needed but the transformation is very fast if you are fit in JavaScript. Then your app will be easily certificated!

Comment: As of 10/9/13, PhoneGap build does not support WP8.

Comment: phonegap build Now supports window phone 8 [check here](http://phonegap.com/blog/2013/10/18/2013-10-18-phonegap-build-support-for-windows-phone-8/)

Comment: @abksharma - I'm using `PhoneGap 3.3.0-0.18.0` and although `wp7` is apparently supported and `wp8` support is _Coming Soon_, it's just hanging at `[phonegap] building the app...`.

Answer (score 0):

Developing a phone gap app is [entirely different](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/app-building) than developing a native app. You are essentially developing in phone gap's style using their api's and then letting them convert it to a xap for you. You do not need Windows 8 to do this as you are not using Microsoft's tools or apis.

Comment: so what you are saying is the part explained in the link would give you a native app and not a phonegap app(bundled with IE 10)?

Comment: The question was regarding the requirement of Windows 8 if using [Phonegap Build](https://build.phonegap.com). Windows is required to run the tools to compile the Windows Phone package (as is MacOS required to compile iOS packages).

Answer (score 0):

There are some discrepancies in the PhoneGap API for Windows Phone so pay close attention to the documentation and make sure to account for any fundamental or plugin-specific incompatibilities. One example being [localStorage lacking support for dot-notation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage_windows_phone_7_quirks):

```
window.localStorage.setItem('itemKey', '');    /* Correct */
window.localStorage.itemKey = ''
```